# How to assign values to String using vector?

Tags: c++, vector

```
struct Books{

std::string title;
std::string author;
std::string des;
int book_id = 0;
char identifier;

} ;

// book 0
book[0].title = "Programming Fundamentals"; // subscript out of range
book[0].author, "Robert Hanks";
book[0].des, "Programming Basics";
book[0].book_id = 101;
book[0].identifier = 'P';

// Struct Object
std::vector <Books> book;
```

When ever I try to compile the above code its giving me a subscript out of range error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have created an empty vector and trying to access it's elements by `book[0]` statement, that is not correct. you need to have atleast one element in the vector before accessing it using `book[0]`.

Initialize your vector to have atleast one element in the vector. I am giving one example below to fix it.

```
  // Struct Object
  std::vector <Books> book(1);

  // book 0
  book[0].title = "Programming Fundamentals"; // subscript out of range
  ....
  ....
```